# Git - Como fazer um pull seletivo para produção?

Tags: git

Tenho o seguinte cenário:
3 programadores (P1,P2,P3) com os seus ambientes locais de produção, um servidor QA para testes e um servidor de produção.
Segundo as regras de negócio da empresa existem modificações no systema que devem ir para produção, mesmo antes de ser testado e como de habitude, existem alterações que devem passar um tempo no QA antes de ser enviada para a produção.

O ambiente de produção só faz PULL do servidor QA, assim como os programadores só fazem pull e push para o QA.

A minha dúvida é quando os 3 programadores P1, P2 e P3 fizerem os seus pushs,para o QA, mas quando eu for fazer o pull de QA para a produção eu só quiser as alterações feitas por P1 e P3. A alteração de P2 vai precisar ficar mais tempo sendo testada.

Não sei como fazer essa separação desses branches no momento do pull - nem sei se é possível.

```
myapp-P1 ---
                  \
myapp-P2 ---        ---> myapp-staging (QA) ---> myapp (Prod)
                  /
myapp-P3 ---
```

Alguém poderia dar uma idéia?

Comment: Já considerou utilizar o [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)?

Comment: Oi Carlos, sim, já passei o dia dando uma olhada no git flow mas não achei nenhuma idéia que pudesse responder a esse cenário. Tbm dei uma lida no www.atlassian.com e não achei nada. POr isso vim perguntar aqui na comunidade para saber como o pessoal lida com issa situação.

Comment: Eu acredito que o git flow lhe atenda ou você pode considerar trabalhar com forks do projeto. Onde cada desenvolvedor terá a sua versão do código e enviará um `pull request` para o repositório principal, assim o QA poderá testar o `pull request` antes de juntar ao código principal. O pipeline do Heroku trabalha dessa forma, [veja](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines).

Comment: @zwitterion o seu contexto é de CI (*continuous integration*, ou integração contínua)? Um build server que faz o push para produção?

Comment: Somos 3 programadores. A empresa tem um repositório central QA, como modifiquei acima. Sim poderia dizer que trabalhamos num lógica de integração contínua, mas as vezes somente 1 programador durante um certo dia é que faz o os pushs. (pq somente ele terminou o código). Ai nesse cenário fica fácil resolver o problema.

Comment: O pior é quando todos fazem o push e o pessoal que testa, descobre que tem uma falha na alteração de um dos programadores mas a produção precisa ser atualizada com o QA instantaneamente, ou quando não queremos deletar o que o programador P2 fez (embora o código dele esteja correto e o pessoal tem que testar em QA, não é o momento de enviar para produção)

Comment: Trabalhe com branchs, e 1 branch será production, nesse branch você so faz marge dos pull requests que devem estar em produção.
E dev você faz  o marge dos branchs a serem testados.

Comment: Você já ouviu falar de Cherry-pick? 
Mas eu acho que você deveria trabalhar melhor no seu processo e estratégia de branch, além de usar essa feature
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick

Comment: Oi @egomesbrandao vou dar uma lida. N'ao conhecia cherry-pick.  E sim, vamos ter que trabalhar melhor essa estratégia de branch. Está dando dor de cabeça.

Comment: @zwitterion Me parece que você precisa de um ambiente intermediário antes da produção. Geralmente é chamado de *staging area*. Serve exatamente para testar erros pós-integração.

Comment: Acredito que vocês precisariam rever essa estratégia de branches. O ideal é que houvesse uma branch de coisas já testadas e que vão para produção, tipo "pré-produção". Assim os desenvolvedores mandariam do QA para pré-produção apenas quando estivesse tudo testado.